# Query on python primitive types and literals

Tags: java, python

After going through this document [link](https://docs.python.org/3.2/index.html), I have following queries:

Q1)
Java has `byte`/`short`/`int`/`long`/`char`/`float`/`double`/`boolean` static types, python document mentions only `int`/`float`/`complex` dynamic types(classes), As everything is object(in python), Can i say that these are the 3 classes that handle primitive values in python?

Q2)
In java, Integer Literal is a Decimal/Hex(start with 0X/0x)/Octal(start with 0) Numeral, What about Integer Literals in python? In java for instance `char` supports value ranges 0-65535 unsigned , What about value ranges in python?

Q3)
In java, Floating-point literal(FPL) is a Decimal FPL or Hexadecimal FPL. Decimal FPL is `<digits><.><digits><ExpPart><f|F|d|D>` where ExpPart consists of `<e|E><+|-><digits>`(the sign is optional). How does Python describe Decimal FPL & Hexadecimal FPL?

Q4)
In Java, Character Literal is  `<'><Character|EscapeSequence><'>` are represented in UTF-16 so supplementary characters cannot be represented by a single literal and require a surrogate pair, Does python support character literal?

Comment: It appears you'd be better served by reading a full introductory text on Python, perhaps one with a focus on people with Java experience.

Comment: @delnan i think this is an introductory tut [link](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/index.html) that i had been thru, but i felt python documentation is not as good as JLS in java world. i could not find answers for abov query

Answer (score 2):

1. There are no special primitive types in Python.
2. Python integers have unlimited length.
3. There are no hexadecimal floating point literals in Python, but it looks like a simple and useful feature that might be reasonable to propose for inclusion in future versions of the language.
4. There are no character literals in Python, only string literals. You can escape any character in a string literal with a 8-digit code (`\Uxxxxxxxx`), or save space on BMP characters with a 4-digit code (`\uxxxx`), or use exotic characters without escaping in an appropriately encoded source file. No hacks.

Comment: lorenzo am unable to write octal numbers for integer literal. Doe we have proper docs  which describe this info.

Comment: There's a manual; octal literals are in a FAQ, https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=octal#how-do-i-specify-hexadecimal-and-octal-integers and in the language reference, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals

Answer (score -1):

A1. sure ... thats reasonable to say if you are talking about numbers ...

A2. Same with python (0x10,010(0o10 in py3),0b1101) and reversing you just call `int('01011',base)` where base is between 2 and 32 (inclusive)

A3. the same I think, Im not really sure what you are asking.  and theres always the decimal class (which stores it as 2 integers)

Q4. no ... python has no single character ... only strings  (you can do something like `chr(ascii_val)` or `unichr(unicode_ordinal)` ) ... in python2 its normal bytestrings in python3 its unicode strings.  you will need to tell it how to decode the bytestring from external sources ... most people use utf8